# How to store controller functions in a service and call them in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I need to execute functions of some controllers when my application ends (e.g. when closing the navigator tab) so I've thought in a service to manage the list of those functions and call them when needed. These functions changes depending on the controllers I have opened.

Here's some code

**Controller 1**

```
angular.module('myApp').component('myComponent', {
controller: function ($scope) {
   var mc = this;
   mc.saveData = function(objectToSave){
     ...
   };
  }
});
```

**Controller 2**

```
angular.module('myApp').component('anotherComponent', {
controller: function ($scope) {
   var ac = this;
   ac.printData = function(objects, priority){
     ...
   };
  }
});
```

How to store those functions (saveData & printData) considering they have different parameters, so when I need it, I can call them (myComponent.saveData & anotherComponent.printData).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make this, creating a service for managing the methods that will be fired.

```
angular.module('FTWApp').service('myService',function(){
    var ac = this;
    ac.addMethodForOnClose = addMethodForOnClose;
    ac.arrMethods = [];
    function addMethodForOnClose(idModule, method){
        ac.arrMethods[idModule] = {
                id: idModule,
                method: method
        }
    };

    function executeMethodsOnClose(){
        for(object in ac.arrayMethods){
           ac.arrMethods[object].method();
        }
});
```

Then in the controllers, just add the method needed to that array:

```
myService.addMethodForOnClose(id, vm.methodToLaunchOnClose);
```

Afterwards, capture the `$window.onunload` and run  `myService.executeMethodsOnClose()`

Answer (score 0):

The above code is not general `controller` but the `angular1.5+ component` with its own controller scope. So the methods `saveData and printData` can only be accessed in respective component HTML template.

So to utilise the above method anywhere in application, they should be part of some `service\factory` and that needs to be injected wherever you may required.

You can create service like :

```
angular.module('FTWApp').service('someService', function() {
    this.saveData = function (objectToSave) { 
    // saveData method code
    };
    this.printData = function (objects, priority) { 
    // printData method code
    }; 
});
```

and inject it wherever you need, like in your component:

```
controller: function(someService) {
    // define method parameter data
    someService.saveData(objectToSave);
    someService.printData (objects, priority);
}
```

Comment: But I want the service just to store and call those functions, not to "own" them. The functions must be in the controllers because I have lots of them and can't have a service with all the functions. Beside the code of those functions is referencing some other functions of their controllers. Thanks!

Comment: please explain the difference between `storing the function and owning the function` ?, I think its same, and further if your method is dependent on the internal component code then its better to have it like same, and only extract minimal code (out of component function) to service, because service needs to be agnostic

Comment: When I said "store" I meant to save the need of calling that method when closing the application. In summary, I need some generic code to manage what methods will be called on closing.

Comment: @M.Laboisse: then I suggest to use the `broadcast` event when you navigate, and  in your component listen for it, via `$scope.$on`, and call your function.